# Where does Visual Studio store the watch window data?

Tags: visual-studio

I use to have some complex expressions in the watch window and out of a sudden the watch window is completely empty now. Of course I can put the expressions back manually but it would be really interesting to know where Visual Studio stores the watch window data? I doubt that it's stored in some solution related file since after a clean build the watches are still there.

I am using Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watch window information is stored in the .suo file for the solution. I couldnt find it in any of the [official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhkhh4zs.aspx) for, but the breakpoints are there and if you configure the watch window, then close VS, then delete the .suo file and open VS the watch window is empty. After closing VS, restoring the .suo file and opening VS again the watch window configuration is back. This is confirmed for instance by [this blog post](https://shemeerns.com/2014/04/04/the-solution-user-options-suo-file-in-visual-studio/):

What informations are saved in my .suo file

> This file is used by Visual Studio to store user/solution specific
>   information such as Opened Files, Expanded Nodes in the Solution
>   Visual Studio .suo fileExplorer, Opened Tool Windows and its
>   Positions, User Tasks, Breakpoints, Start-up Project, Contents of
>   Watch window, Whether the project is loaded/unloaded  etc. The same
>   file is used by Visual Studio Addins (VSPackages) to persist
>   information that are specific to that solution/user.

I don't know where your .suo file went though, did you accidentally delete it?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The weird thing is that all my breakpoints are still there. Just the watch window is empty. Will try your suggestion and let you know about the result.

Comment: Hmm, that is strange. Did you maybe terminate VS instead of properly closing, so that the file wasn't saved correctly?

Comment: Nope. VS was still running when I came to the office the morning. By the way: The same happened to a colleague also running Windows 10. Other colleagues on Windows 7/8 still have their watch window as they left them yesterday. Oh and we don't have SUO files for this specific solutions so I can't do what you suggested.

Comment: Are you 100% sure there is no suo file?? (note it's a hidden file) That would go against the official documentation which states it's used for breakpoints, which you do have?

Comment: Yeah just found that it's hidden. Since the `dir` command defaults to visible files only I haven't thought of that. Testing...

Comment: It seems as if the watch window data is stored in the SUO file, as long with the comments and breakpoints. The weird thing is that the latter two are still there. Thanks for your help!